# How do I make python script wait for pyqt button selection before continuing?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a pyqt5 button into a python script and pause the script so it waits for the button press before it continues.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
                
        self.ui.button.clicked.connect(pyfile.dothething)
        self.ui.button2.clicked.connect(pyfile.dotheotherthing)
```

---

```
def do_the_stuff():
    do some stuff
    wait for button press
    do_the_stuff()
```

the do_the_stuff() is going to ignore the button since normal python is not event based.
How do I insert an event based wait function in the normal python script so it waits until the pyqt button is pressed?

Comment: Using a QMessageBox as a popup window is a good way to wait for user interaction, would that meet your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The buttons are inside a vstack box in the mainwindow. I'm trying to make it so the buttons appear/disappear when needed and the python script will pause and wait for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add state to your normal code to enable the flow control. For example:

```
class NormalCode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 0

    def do_the_stuff(self):
        do some stuff
        while self.state == 0:
            # Prevent hammering the CPU
            time.sleep(0.1)
        do_the_stuff()
```

Then your button click can simply change the state:

```
def on_button_clicked(self):
    self.normal_code.state = 1
```

This should be fairly clean to implement as the normal code still doesn't need to know that the Qt layer exists.